# What does a column assignment using an aggregate in the columns area of a select do?

Tags: t-sql, select, subquery

I'm trying to decipher another programmer's code who is long-gone, and I came across a select statement in a stored procedure that looks like this (simplified) example:

```
SELECT #Table2.Col1, Table2.Col2, Table2.Col3, MysteryColumn = CASE WHEN y.Col3 IS NOT NULL THEN #Table2.MysteryColumn - y.Col3 ELSE #Table2.MysteryColumn END
    INTO #Table1
    FROM #Table2
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT Table3.Col1, Table3.Col2, Col3 = SUM(#Table3.Col3)
            FROM Table3
                INNER JOIN #Table4 ON Table4.Col1 = Table3.Col1 AND Table4.Col2 = Table3.Col2
                GROUP BY Table3.Col1, Table3.Col2
        ) AS y ON #Table2.Col1 = y.Col1 AND #Table2.Col2 = y.Col2
    WHERE #Table2.Col2 < @EnteredValue
```

My question, what does the fourth column of the primary selection do? does it produce a boolean value checking to see if the values are equal? or does it set the #Table2.MysteryColumn equal to some value and then inserts it into #Table1?  Or does it just update the #Table2.MysteryColumn and not output a value into #Table1?

This same thing seems to happen inside of the sub-query on the third column, and I am equally at a loss as to what that does as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MysteryColumn =` gives the expression a name also called a column alias. The fact that a column in the table#2 also has the same name is besides the point.

Since it uses `INTO` syntax it also gives the column its name in the resulting temporary table. See the [SELECT CLAUSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms176104.aspx) and note `| column_alias = expression` and the [INTO CLAUSE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)

Comment: So it's just an obscure syntax for an alias?

Comment: *grumble grumble grumble* ...wish people would just use the standards... *grumble grumble*

Comment: [Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand) argues [in this article](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) that = is better than `as`. Personally I use `as` but he makes some good points.

Comment: He does make some good points, but he leaves out some good counter-points.  For example, if you have a SQL Variable, you can use that exact same syntax and it becomes an assignment instead of an alias if you just type the variable name instead of column name.  Also, the fact that there is a built-in keyword to define aliases suggests to me that the intended syntax is AS.